# Can't disable error reporting in OpenCart (PHP)

Tags: php, opencart, error-reporting, ini-set

I can't seem to disable error reporting in PHP - I have tried everything but "Notice" errors are still displayed.

My php.ini has

```
display_errors = Off;
error_reporting = 0;
```

My .htaccess has

```
php_value error_reporting 0
```

And my script has

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'Off');

php_info();

echo $my_undefined_var;
```

The php_info() output confirms that display_errors and error_reporting are indeed off and 0, and yet I still get a notice,

> Notice: Undefined variable: my_undefined_var in /my/site/path/index.php?blahblah...

Note this is an OpenCart website (and my change is in the Admin section). I have tried creating a test php script in the same directory as index.php and it's fine.

Is there anything else that could be overriding the `error_reporting(0)` ?

I've done a grep of the entire site to find and disable all mentions of the error_reporting and display_errors but to no avail.

Comment: What's the point in setting log_errors to 1? What do you want to log?

Comment: Besides that, the title makes me shiver naturally.

Comment: I don't really want to log anything... I was reading on another forum that to disable error displaying you may have to enable error logging - doesn't make sense to me but I am at the point where I'll try anything. But if I take it out it makes no difference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986806/how-can-we-disable-error-log-in-opencart-error-store-on-databse/29986840#29986840

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a setting within the OpenCart dashboard that allows you to turn on (or off) error reporting and logging.

1. Log into your dashboard
2. In the menu, go to "System" and select "Settings"
3. In the list of stores, click "Edit" for your store
4. Click the "Server" tab.
5. Scroll down, and there's two settings:
   a. Log Errors - set this as desired
   b. Display Errors - set this to "No"

Answer (score 11):

As @colmde already pointed OpenCart uses custom error_handler.

You can turn error displaying off without any code edits (especially OpenCart core files) via:

`Admin->System->Settings->[edit your configured store]->Server->Display Errors`

[EDIT]
You can do the same by running following query against OpenCart database:

```
update setting set `value`= 1 where `key` = 'config_error_display'
```

Comment: For me worked:

`UPDATE 'TABLENAME'.'oc_setting' SET 'value' = '0' WHERE 'oc_setting'.'setting_id'=1057;`

Comment: Perfectly valid, and the reason is that you selected to use `oc_` prefix for OpenCart tables during setup, so `setting` turned into `oc_setting`.

Answer (score 8):

OpenCart uses the `set_error_handler()` function which causes it to override the `error_reporting(0)`.

Removing this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

on system/startup.php

Comment: I wanted to do the opposite: turn error reporting on (which turned out to be quite hard, but this works!)

Answer (score 0):

True way in OpenCart.

```
 $this->config->set('config_error_display', 0);
 $this->processAction(); // it throws ugly warning
```

I've tested in the ***controller*** of my module.
Just to turn off showing errors before your code. 
It affects only current session (perhaps even current page). 
It doesn't affect the DB!

Answer (score 0):

for me helped:
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

in file startup.php